# The definition of random sequence

Tags: soft-question, random-variables

Suppose that I ask you to tell me four integers between $0$ and $10$ randomly. You tell your numbers, for example $\{3,7,2, 5\}$. However I don't trust you about your numbers being random, hence I search these numbers on [OEIS](https://oeis.org). I find that your numbers are following the following pattern:

> Triangle in which first row is 1, n-th row (n>1) lists distinct prime factors of n.
>
> 1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 2, 5, 11, 2, 3, 13, 2, 7, 3, 5, 2, 17,
>   2, 3, 19, 2, 5, 3, 7, 2, 11, 23, 2, 3, 5, 2, 13, 3, 2, 7, 29, 2, 3, 5,
>   31, 2, 3, 11, 2, 17, 5, 7, 2, 3, 37, 2, 19, 3, 13, 2, 5, 41, 2, 3, 7,
>   43, 2, 11, 3, 5, 2, 23, 47, 2, **3, 7, 2, 5**, 3, 17, 2, 13, 53, 2, 3, 5,
>   11, 2, 7, 3, 19, 2, 29, 59, 2, 3, 5, 61, 2, 31

I call you lair but you insist that your numbers were randomly told. I ask you to tell another sequence, this time five numbers. You say $\{9,1,0,4,3\}$. However this sequence is also following a pattern:

> Decimal expansion of log_12 (20).
>
> +20 22 1, 2, 0, 5, 5, 7, 1, 3, 5,
>   3, 6, 8, 0, 2, 5, 6, 6, 5, 9, 3, 0, 4, 0, 3, 7, 5, 0, 9, 2, 0, 4, 9,
>   7, 8, 6, 0, 7, 1, 0, 6, 3, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 4, 5, 4, 6, 2, 7,
>   5, 0, 4, 0, 5, 7, 0, 5, 2, 6, 7, 0, 7, 5, 8, 9, **9, 1, 0, 4, 3**, 1, 4,
>   1, 8, 3, 4, 2, 9, 0, 3, 1, 6, 9, 3, 5, 3, 8, 5, 2, 2, 5, 9, 2

You still insist your numbers are randomly thought. Now I doubt my definition of randomness. So I am asking you guys on MSE: not following a pattern is a sufficient condition for a sequence to be random, or is it really a condition? What is exactly the definition of randomness? Wikipedia tells too much so it confuses me.

Comment: The numbers can be told randomly, but that does not exclude that they are part of a sequence, which is not random.

Comment: But how can I be sure that he told the sequence randomly?

Comment: @nikamed You need only accept that the method used to generate each number is subject to uncertainty, and then witness the generation of each number (or else trust that the party did so.). It has nothing to do with checking some absolute definition of randomness. If you are looking at finitely many elements of the chosen sequence after this has been done, then you will have no idea if the person is telling the truth or not. That is not a matter of mathematics, at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Random by itself doesn't mean much. There are 'patterns' or distributions of random (uniform, normal, Poisson, etc). Each distribution is a way of assigning a 'likelihood' or probability to certain events occuring in an experiment.